# How to get apache version in php?

Tags: php

I know this question has been asked/answered on this site multiple times, But my question is a little diffrent. I have already reviewed some of those posts and what I got from there is :

```
 <?Php 
 echo apache_get_version();?>
```

I know this function returns the Apache version.

My website is on a free webhost [eu5.org](http://eu5.org) where they have disabled both **phpinfo()** and **apache_get_version()** And because of this I am not able to know which version I am using.

Is there any other way to get the server version in php?

Thanks!

Comment: simply type localhost in your url,click phpinfo()

Comment: Contact them and ask them.

Comment: Maybe something like `shell_exec('apache2 -v');`

Comment: @whyte624 i doubt free hosting will allow `shell_exec()` or `exec()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jaswsinc/97c72252531277f7aa19) provides probably the best fallback I've seen if the apache_get_version function is disabled.

Basically you need to define a function that uses the operating system to call the httpd daemon directly to get the version information. Although, in your situation, it's likely that OS commands are also disabled so this might not be terrible helpful.

Answer (score 2):

if you cannot use `php_info` and `apache_get_version` functions you can try this one:
`echo $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']`;